# Forwarding to different IP addresses depending on which application I use

Tags: github, server, dns, ip, putty

Is there anyway that I can go from a server to a website depending whether you use PuTTY or a browser? I have 1 domain using GoDaddy and I want it to go to a server when using PuTTY but a website when using a browser.

[This is what I have so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/conwT.png)

By the way I am using GitHub pages for the browser side of things.

Comment: Both SSH and HTTP are based of TCP/IP. So you need the same IP (one setting in DNS), but obviously each uses its own port (22 for SSH, 80/443 for HTTP), so you have nothing specific to do to achieve your goal. If you want different server then you need either IP level forwarding for ssh or HTTP level proxying/redirect. That seems obviously complex for no good reasons, just use different names each mapping to the correct IP address. But otherwise your question is offtopic here as not very related to programming.

Comment: PS: Don't use images, put the relevant textual data as text in your question.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP (port 80 and 443) is an end user protocol, SSH is an admin protocol.
The semantics (meaning rules) behind the Domain Name protocol, is that names represent an IP address, and they in turn represent a physical server.

While it is technically possible to break the semantic rules of a protocol, it  is not convenient to do so, as it would make maintenance harder by making the design more opaque. If these were both end user protocols I would understand if maintenance ease were sacrificed for the sake of user ease, but you are trying to create an abstraction for admins, which will only make debugging harder.

The solution is to use a different name for a different server, you can use a subdomain, for example, by using ssh.domain.com if the endpoint is a bastion host that tunnels connections to domain.com, or just use a different domain name altogether if it's a completely different service.